# Controlling an Arduino with Flutter

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, usb, flutter

I am wanting to create an app to control an Arduino using either USB or Bluetooth. Does anyone know if this is possible and/or have any suggestions on resources that I could use to learn how to do this?

Comment: check out this library `flutter_bluetooth_serial` .. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial.
i didn't use it personally but it looks promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, flutter as of now does not have any bluetooth serial library which is actually needed to communicate with an Arduino.

One way that you can use flutter apps to control Arduino would be to just use `ESP8266` wifi shield and control Arduino via api calls or socket connection.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How about USB serial?